# Some divs didn't appear during web-scraping

Tags: python, html, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I'm new to web-scraping and I try to scrape the content from this website:[INFOBANJIR JPS SELANGOR](http://infobanjirjps.selangor.gov.my/rainfall-data.html?lang=en)

This is the content that I'm trying to scrape:
[ONLINE RAINFALL DATA (MM)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IJcfw.png)

This is my code:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests

url = 'http://infobanjirjps.selangor.gov.my/flood-gauge-data.html?districtId=4&lang=en'
page = requests.get(url)

soup = BeautifulSoup(page.text, 'html')

soup.find_all('table', id='tableRainfall')
```

But, the output only shows this
[Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0SUjA.png)

Then, I try to find the div by using id = 'tableDataRainfall', but still, the output shows the same thing as before.

It seems like the html inside of the division is missing. I'm sorry if it's a stupid question, but I just wanna know why. Thank you in advance!

Comment: Loaded by Javascript after the initial page request, use Selenium or try to find the API calls in the network request logs in the Browser Developer Tools

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The data you see on the page is loaded from different URL via JavaScript (so BeautifulSoup doesn't see it). Here is an example how you can load the information for this site:

```py
import pandas as pd
import requests

api_url = "http://infobanjirjps.selangor.gov.my/JPSAPI/api/StationRainfalls/GetRFAllStationData/1"

data = requests.get(api_url).json()

for d in data["stations"]:
    for r in d.pop("previousReadings"):
        d[r["dataDate"]] = r["dailyRainfall"]

df = pd.DataFrame(data["stations"])
print(df)
```

Prints:

```
   markerType   id  stationId                 stationName    districtName           lastUpdate  hourlyRainfall  todayRainfall stationCode    referenceName  mode    z1     z2    z3  batteryLevel  stationStatus  latitude   longitude     gsmNumber  21/02/2024  22/02/2024  23/02/2024  24/02/2024  25/02/2024  26/02/2024  27/02/2024
0    Rainfall  160    3214056                    SRI AMAN  KUALA SELANGOR  27/02/2024 02:30:00               0              0    BKSL0004          SRIAMAN  True  True   True  True          12.9              1  3.237748  101.477205  601592019217         0.0         1.0         0.0           8           0         0.0           0
1    Rainfall  161    3414032              RANTAU PANJANG  KUALA SELANGOR  27/02/2024 02:30:00               0              0    BKSL0001         RPANJANG  True  True   True  True          12.5              1  3.401811  101.441718   60122024643         2.5         1.0         6.5           3           0         0.0           0
2    Rainfall  217    3313045                  KG. ASAHAN  KUALA SELANGOR  27/02/2024 02:30:00               0              0    BKSL0006         KGASAHAN  True  True   True  True          13.0              1  3.366076  101.346635   60122674195         0.5         0.0         6.0           0           0         0.0           0
3    Rainfall  220    3312046  TELUK PENYAMUN (PINTU AIR)  KUALA SELANGOR  27/02/2024 02:30:00               0              0    BKSL0002    KUALASELANGOR  True  True   True  True          12.9              1  3.332439  101.259526   60122065279         0.0         0.0       122.5           0           9         0.5           0
4    Rainfall  219    3313070                PARIT MAHANG  KUALA SELANGOR  27/02/2024 02:45:00               0              0    BKSL0005      PARITMAHANG  True  True   True  True          12.9              1  3.297236  101.378453  601592855131         0.0         0.0         1.0           1           0         0.0           0
5    Rainfall  249    3411017       STOR J.P.S TG. KARANG  KUALA SELANGOR  27/02/2024 02:30:00               0              0    BKSL0011  STORJPSTGKARANG  True  True   True  True          12.7              1  3.423624  101.171665   60172175936         0.0         0.0         2.0           0           0         0.0           0
6    Rainfall  250    3411018        P/A PEKAN TG. KARANG  KUALA SELANGOR  27/02/2024 02:30:00               0              0    BKSL0009       PATGKARANG  True  True   True  True          12.9              1  3.428279  101.176409   60172175891         0.0         0.0         1.5           0           0         0.0           0
7    Rainfall  252    3412001       IBU BEKALAN SG. TENGI  KUALA SELANGOR  27/02/2024 02:30:00               0              0    BKSL0018    IBUBKLSGTENGI  True  True  False  True          12.8              1  3.482524  101.218658   60172175941         0.0         0.0         0.5           0           0         0.0           0
8    Rainfall  253    3312047                P/A SG. YU 1  KUALA SELANGOR  27/02/2024 02:30:00               0              0    BKSL0010          PASGYU1  True  True   True  True          12.9              1  3.363235  101.239092   60172175897         0.5         0.0        75.0           0           0         0.0           0
9    Rainfall  269    3313060            LADANG SG. BULOH  KUALA SELANGOR  27/02/2024 02:30:00               0              0    BKSL0012       LDGSGBULOH  True  True   True  True          12.6              1  3.308964   101.31875   60122634952         0.0         0.0        28.5           0           0         0.0           0
10   Rainfall  270    3213057     LADANG BRAUNSTON, JERAM  KUALA SELANGOR  27/02/2024 02:30:00               0              0    BKSL0013     LDGBRAUNSTON  True  True   True  True          12.7              1   3.24891  101.315949   60122634955         0.0         0.5        15.0           0           0         0.0           0
11   Rainfall  278    3314001        RUMAH PAM JAYA SETIA  KUALA SELANGOR  27/02/2024 02:30:00               0              0    BKSL0015             RPJS  True  True   True  True          12.9              1  3.369056  101.410889   60126748104        18.5         0.5         1.5           2           0         0.0           0
12   Rainfall  279    3411016           PARIT 1 SG BURONG  KUALA SELANGOR  26/02/2024 20:00:00               0              0    BKSL0016           PRT1SB  True  True   True  True          13.0              3  3.455814     101.146   60124594182         0.0         5.0         6.5           0           0         0.0           0
13   Rainfall  877  0210671RF              KG. LUBUK JAYA  KUALA SELANGOR  27/02/2024 02:30:00               0              0    BKSL0023    KG LUBOK JAYA  True  True   True  True          12.8              1  3.385003  101.299811  601592188690         0.0         0.0       136.0           0           0         0.0           0
14   Rainfall  878  0200111RF          KG. BUKIT KERAYONG  KUALA SELANGOR  27/02/2024 02:30:00               0              0    BKSL0022  KG BKT KERAYUNG  True  True   True  True          13.1              1  3.197979  101.400665  601592728502         0.0         0.0        26.0           0           0         0.0           0
```

Comment: I can finally scrape the website by using selenium but wow, I don't know that you can scrape as simple as this one. Thank you so much!!

Comment: Btw, sorry for interrupting, but may i know how did you get api url from the website?

Comment: @HafizRamli When you open Web Developer Tools -> Network tab in your browser, reload the page you should see this URL there.

Answer (score 0):

I'd be glad to help you with web scraping the content you're interested in from the given website. However, I'm unable to access the specific content due to potential restrictions or limitations on the website itself. I'll provide general guidance and best practices that you can adapt to your specific situation.

Understanding Dynamic Content Rendering:

JavaScript-Generated Content: If the content you're trying to scrape is dynamically generated using JavaScript, the HTML structure might not be readily available in the initial page load. This means using BeautifulSoup directly on the fetched HTML might not yield the desired results.
Approaches for Dynamic Content Scraping:

Browser Automation (Selenium):

Install selenium and webdriver_manager using pip install selenium webdriver_manager.
Choose a suitable browser driver (e.g., chromedriver for Chrome) and set up the WebDriver path using webdriver_manager.ChromeDriverManager().install().
Create a Selenium WebDriver instance to control the browser and simulate user interactions.
Use JavaScript execution methods (e.g., execute_script) to wait for the content to be loaded dynamically.
Once the content is available, proceed with scraping using BeautifulSoup or other methods.
Python

```
import time
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get(url)

# Wait for the content to load (replace with appropriate selectors/conditions)
WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(
    EC.presence_of_element_located((By.ID, "tableRainfall"))
)

soup = BeautifulSoup(driver.page_source, 'html')
tables = soup.find_all('table', id='tableRainfall')
# Process the scraped content
```

Use code with caution.
API-Based Approach (if available):

Check if the website provides an API that offers access to the data you need. APIs are designed for programmatic data retrieval and often provide a structured format (e.g., JSON, XML) that's easier to parse.
If an API is available, use appropriate libraries or tools (e.g., requests) to make API requests and handle the response data.
Important Considerations:

Respect website terms and conditions: Avoid overloading the website with excessive requests or violating scraping guidelines.
Handle potential errors: Implement error handling mechanisms to gracefully handle situations where the content might not be available or the scraping process encounters issues.
Be mindful of legal and ethical aspects: Ensure that your scraping activities comply with all applicable laws and regulations.
Remember to replace placeholders like "tableRainfall" with the actual IDs or selectors from the website you're targeting. Adapt the code based on the website's structure and the specific content you want to extract.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: After 2 days of learning and trying, I can finally scrape that website thanks to your contribution. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

See this [website](https://www.zenrows.com/blog/dynamic-web-pages-scraping-python#alternatives) for some information about dynamic web page scraping. `requests` and `beautifulSoup` aren't enough to run JavaScript on a website; you need more powerful tools.